# How to wrap stacked facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

In my data.frame `df`, I have variables `A, B, C` and `D`. I would like to plot `C` vs `D`, and facet with `A` and `B`. `B` is a factor with 3 levels and I would like for it to be facetted vertically, and `A` has many variables which I would like faceted horizontally. However, when I do

```
sp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=D, y=C)) + geom_point()
sp + facet_grid(B ~ A)
```

the plot extends too far horizontally. I would like to use `facet_wrap` horizontally (with `A`), but use `facet_grid` vertically so that the `B` variables don't become misaligned. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide sample reproducible sample data otherwise it is hard to answer to your problem.

Comment: The short answer is you [can't](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/156). Technically you can produce anything you want if you drill all the way down to the **grid** code itself, but it wouldn't be easy in this case.

Comment: How many variables in A? Do you accept a lattice solution?

Comment: About 40 different values in A. If lattice is separate from ggplot2, then no--I prefer a ggplot2 solution. My current hack is looping through the values in A and subsetting `df` and writing the ggplots as separate pages to a pdf. I'd prefer a facet solution, though.

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV yes `lattice` is independent of `ggplot2`. Do you want to get all the plots in the same page? 40x3 plots?!!

Comment: Yes, a bit too many for a single page :) I had assumed faceting was capable of automatically extending to multiple pages when necessary, but after searching more it doesn't seem so. Like I mentioned, I'm currently looping through the values of A and printing to several pages, but would prefer if there were a simple faceting solution that took care of it for multiple pages.